# Is there any way to run unittest from button click on django sites?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have written unit tests as well the django documentation. I can run tests from `python manage.py test`. That's good. But, I want to run test from a button click. This button can be anywhere in my UI. Also I want to generate a simple report on passed or failed.
Is it possible with Python/Django `unittest` module?

Comment: IMHO running unittests inside the system you are testing is not a good idea. You would have to assume the system you want to test is working to test it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds very strange to run your tests inside the web app. I'd be worried about the database settings for the test database interfering with the default database settings.

However, if I really wanted to do this, I'd try making a call to [`call_command('test')`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django.core.management.call_command) from within a view method. Good luck, and you should probably disable it in production.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried with `os.system` command. And I'm thinking not to do that.

Comment: `os.system` starts a separate process, but `call_command()` calls a Django management command directly in the same process. They're not the same thing, @AshrafulIslam.

Comment: Ow. I see. Then I must try this. Thanks a lot.